# How many bytes does an unsigned DECIMAL(3,2) use in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sqldatatypes

I was wondering how many bytes an unsigned DECIMAL(3,2) uses in SQL. The documentation that I find online is not very clear, especially not when you have an unsigned DECIMAL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) seems pretty clear:

> Values for DECIMAL columns are stored using a binary format that packs
> nine decimal digits into 4 bytes. The storage requirements for the
> integer and fractional parts of each value are determined separately.
> Each multiple of nine digits requires 4 bytes, and any remaining
> digits left over require some fraction of 4 bytes.  The storage
> required for remaining digits is given by the following table.

So, the integer part of `DECIMAL(3, 2)` has 1 digit and the fractional part has 2 digits.  According to the table, 1-2 digits require one byte.  Hence the total is two bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer, which is usually correct or very close:

The storage requirement for `DECIMAL(m,n)` is `m/2`.

In your case 3/2 = 1.5 is very close.  In this case, round up to get the correct "2".